# Why won't my Ionic Cordova App send anything other than OPTIONS when it should be sending POST and GET methods?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, cors, http-post

Im building an app with Ionic and Cordova and Angular using Larvel PHP as the backend. When I try to login to my app on my IOS device it's only sending OPTIONS to my API and not the POST method like it's supposed to. It only does this on IOS. It works as expected on the the web and when I send the POST method on Postman. I think it has something todo with CORS but im stuck and I can't figure it out.

Ive tried and looked at my PHP files in routes/api.php and my AuthenticationController and it still only shows up as an OPTION method on my logs and the user isn't rerouted into my app.

Here is my api.php:

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;use App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticationController;use App\Http\Controllers\TripsController;use App\Http\Controllers\VehiclesController;use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {return $request->user();});

//register new user
Route::post('/register', [AuthenticationController::class, 'register']);

//login user
Route::post('/login', [AuthenticationController::class, 'login']);

//using middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {Route::get('/profile', function (Request $request) {return auth()->user();});`
```

Here is my AuthenticationController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Validator;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'firstname' => 'required|string',
            'lastname' => 'required|string',
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $validator->messages()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'id' => Str::uuid()->toString(),
            'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $request->input('lastname'),
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Login information is invalid.'
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = auth()->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely need to configure your server for CORS. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

Cors is a common problem in ionic applications since the app is implemented  into mobile app within a WebView which have a URL localhost which will be sent to any backend within any request done and thus many backends will treat the request is invalid since the origin of it is being localhost..

To solve this problem their is three ways and will mention them below.

**But you need to know i only advice to work using the first way since second and third way will be make your server vulnerable but you can use them just to do your testing before going into production but you will need to make sure to remove them before releasing your project..**

1. The first is to use **advanced http plugin** which sends the request
   as a normal native mobile app (native requests sends no origin thus
   origin will not be send and request will be treated as a valid
   request) **[safest and best recommended approach]**:

   https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/http

   For Cordova apps:

   ```
   $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http 
   $ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/http
   ```

   For Capacitor apps:

   ```
   $ npm install cordova-plugin-advanced-http 
   $ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/http 
   $ ionic cap sync
   ```
2. The Second way is to solve it from Laravel side through adding the
   following code inside **bootstrap/app.php**:

   ```
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
   ```
3. The Third way is by editing your server **htaccess** file and additing the following lines:

   ```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
   ```